# Nested aggregate columns into array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to have for each `app` I want to store an array `series`, where each element is the amount of `conversations` created that given day.

Any idea how this can be accomplished? This is what I got so far

```
with week as
(
   SELECT now()::date - d AS day FROM generate_series (0, 90) as d
)
select
  a.id, week.day, count(extract(dow from c.inserted_at))
from week 
left join conversations c on week.day = c.inserted_at::date
left join apps a on c.app_id = a.id
group by a.id, week.day
order by week.day;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to summarize data to a certain level.  Your group by determines the level of aggregation.  You have a group by of Id and Week.day.  If ID is the unique identity value of the record.  You are not grouping or summarizing at the Week.day level you are doing it at the id level.  You need to remove the ID from your group by and just have week.day in your grouping to aggregate to the day level.

Comment: Can you give an examplee? I cannot remove the ID because else it complains that it is not being used in an aggregate function